# How to access to user data through intermediate table (hasOneThrough / hasManyThrough)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, eloquent-relationship

For a job posting application, I have three tables, which shortly are defined as:

**applications:**

- *id* as primary key
- *job_offer_uuid* as external key

**job_offers:**

- *uuid* as primary key
- *user_id* as external key

**users:**

- Just laravel normal users table with *id* as primary key

Because I need to notify job_offer owner (a member of User model) any time that an application is registered, I'm trying to create a hasOneThrough or hasManyThrough relationship from applications to users, but without success for the moment.

**For clarification:**
*User* model only hosts users that publish job offers, and any user can publish many job offers. There is not applicants in `users` table

Based on my understanding of eloquent documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through), my actual code in Application model is:

```
public function publisher()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(User::class, JobOffer::class, 'job_offer_uuid', 'user_id');
}
```

But it fires an SQL error:

`` SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'job_offers.job_offer_uuid' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `job_offers`.`job_offer_uuid` as `laravel_through_key` from `users` inner join `job_offers` on `job_offers`.`id` = `users`.`user_id` where `job_offers`.`job_offer_uuid` in (1) ``

using hasManyThrough instead, I got an identical error:

`` SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'job_offers.job_offer_uuid' in 'field list' (SQL: select `users`.*, `job_offers`.`job_offer_uuid` as `laravel_through_key` from `users` inner join `job_offers` on `job_offers`.`id` = `users`.`user_id` where `job_offers`.`job_offer_uuid` in (1)) ``

I can get accurate results using pure SQL with a sentence like this:

`` select applications.id, applications.job_offer_uuid, job_offers.uuid, job_offers.user_id, users.id, users.name, users.email from `applications` inner join job_offers on `applications`.`job_offer_uuid` = `job_offers`.`uuid` join users on job_offers.user_id = users.id where `applications`.id = 1 ``

Any video or tutorial that I found related to this point are using the final table with a foreign key to the intermediate table, and thats means my User model should have a foreign job_offer_id key, but that make no sense to me.

Any clarification should be truly appreciate. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. You have to define relationship in User Model as follow:

```
public function publisher()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        Application::class,
        JobOffer::class,
        'user_id', // Foreign key on job_offers table
        'job_offer_uuid', // Foreign key on applications table
        'id', // Local key on user table
        'uuid' // Local key on job_offer table
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Pradeep Darjee, I will try your solution but it seems that it will access to applications records which belongs to a particular user. And in that case it should be `hasManyThrough` because an user can publish many job_offers.
In the other side an application can only belongs to one job offer and a job offer can only belongs to one user. 
That is what I can achieve with my pure SQL sentence posted at the end of my question.